# Cloning a SQL Server database to another collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm not sure if this is the best way to migrate data to another collation but I've done the following:

1) Scripted the source database and changed the collation in the script to my required one

2) Ran the script and created the new database with the wanted collation (along with all the tables,triggers,indexes etc.

3) I tried to 'Export Data' from the SQL Server management studio but I got an error related to code page differences.

4) Since Export/Import Data didn't work, I resorted to using bcp to mass export all the tables in the source database to txt files. After that I began importing the rows using bcp but I saw some errors related to truncation and invalid characters.

What's the best/proper way to migrate the data from a database with a different code page & collation after creating the clone from the scripted source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had to change the collation of a whole database... Wasn't easy...

These were the steps:

- copied the db
- deleted everything besides the naked tables (indexes, views, functions, procedures, constraints, trigger ...)
- changed the collations of textual columns semi-automatically (-> `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` are good to start off)
- used a tool (red gate ?) to compare with the copy and find all differences.
- this tool creates a difference script and - that's important! - one can configure to create this script without collation hints.
- Finally I applied the diff script (some manual work left...)

It might be easier to go the other way round and start of with a create script for just your tables without collation hints and do the rest against this... But my approach made it possible to let the data untouched.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I also thought the create script first approach would be easier since I don't have to delete and recreate all the indexes,constraints,views etc. but now I'm facing the issue of copying the raw data rows from my source database to the newly created

Comment: @AuthenticReplica Exactly!, It was easier for me to re-create all side objects and let the data remain were it was... There are great tools for this. If you are using Visual Studio a very mighty db tool is part of the package...

Comment: @AuthenticReplica, was this answer helpful? Do you need further help?

Comment: I'm very persistent with my initial method :P I'm still trying to find a way to copy just row data into my newly created database. There has to be some complete way to do this.